# Need some help in inline matrix and mark allocation

Tags: equations, matrices

I am new to Latex. I need some help with LaTeX editing.

I am required by my course supervisor to copy a few exam questions as exercise. Below are the questions (some are hidden to avoid troubles):

[image: questions]

Here are my following questions:

1. How can I input the inline matrix equation as shown? I have tried the Overleaf solution, but the output is awful.

   ```latex
   Trying to typeset an inline matrix here
   $\begin{pmatrix}
   a & b\\ 
   c & d
   \end{pmatrix}$ 
   but it looks too big, so let's try 
   $\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
   a & b\\
   c & d
   \end{smallmatrix}\big)$ 
   instead.
   ```
2. Also, how can I type in the mark indication (i.e. the circled `[6 points]`) as the format shown in the picture? I asked my tutor and was told that "\hfill" might help. However, it didn't work.

I use the following format for the listing:

[image]

I would be grateful if someone can help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE. Please show us what you try so far. The best in form of small complete document (called MWE; Minimal Working Example), which we can test as it is and which reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
\item   Trying to typeset an inline matrix here as \verb+pmatrix+: $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\  c & d \end{pmatrix}$  but it looks too big, so let's try to use \verb+psmallmatrix+: $\begin{psmallmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{psmallmatrix}$  instead.
\hfill [6 points]

\item   
Trying 
    \marginpar{[6 points]}
to typeset an inline matrix as \verb+psmallmatrix+ defined in the package here $\begin{psmallmatrix} a & b\\  c & d \end{psmallmatrix}$  gives hopefully satisfactory result. Here the point achieved solving this task is in page margin. Instruction for it should be inserted after firs word in theparagraph/item.

\item
One
    \marginpar{[6 points]}
more possibilities id us \verb+mpamtrix+ defined in the \verb+nccmath+ package: $\Bigl(\begin{mmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{mmatrix}\Bigr)$ which gives medium sized matrix which you may liked :-). Here the point achieved at solving this task is in page margin as in previous case. Instruction for it should be inserted after firs word in the paragraph.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)